# extract html titles above url

Tags: awk, sed, wget

when i use this command

```
wget --quiet -O - http://www.some-site.com | egrep -e '/player/episode/[^"]*" title="[.?]*' | awk -F'"' '{print $2$4}' >> new.txt
```

it saves a list of url's and titles in a txt file like this

```
/player/episode/g0656bgp/the-night-manager-episode-4The Night Manager, Episode 4
```

i would like it to save like this

```
The Night Manager, Episode 4
/player/episode/g0656bgp/the-night-manager-episode-4
```

with the title above the url
for every url and title

i can use sed awk wget grep

thanks

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump requirements/to-do lists

Comment: looking at the many questions asked on this site there are many questions asked about all sorts of things not just programming  i cant see whats wrong with my question?

Comment: If your have access to xmlstarlet upload an example HTML page somewhere.

Comment: thanks for reply cyrus i have no access to xmlstarlet i thought this could be done with sed awk egrep etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```bash
wget --quiet -O - http://www.some-site.com | egrep -e '/player/episode/[^"]*" title="[.?]*' | awk -F'"' '{print $4"\n"$2}' >> new.txt
```

Compared to your original code, only `awk` was changed:

- re-arranged field order to put field 4 first before field 2
- then a `"\n"` to insert a new line between them

So this successfully results in the title being above the URL as you wanted. As long as your original code worked for you, this should work too.

Comment: thank you user454038 that worked i have asked about 4 question on this site and and all the guys here have been very helpfull  Marc B please chill out